# No black wire coming from ceiling to wire a ceiling fan

Tags: wiring

[image]I am replacing the ceiling fan in my bedroom. I was checking the wires and it appears that the wires coming from the ceiling are white, green, copper and gray. I do not see a black wire. What should I do?

Comment: Conduit or cable? Where are you? The NEC used to specify that "*natural* grey" was specified as reserved for neutral, dark gray was allowed as a hot. You likely need a  voltage tester to confirm what you have.

Comment: Picture would help.

Comment: I am in West Virginia

Answer (score 2):

You have a cable coming in the middle that has a White + Black + copper. The black appears as gray since it is covered with dust.

With power off wipe it clean.